# Is it possible to create a desktop app using facebook oauth 2.0 authentication without requiring a browser interaction?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to have a client app which can authenticate using Facebook but without requiring browser(I mean no embedded browser in the code)?? User inputs the username/password and allow access to app using the client app only.

Any Suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks,
Tara Singh

Edit: I have created app in Python which requires browser interaction. Now I want to get rid of that and do it using my client app only. Any Links/Tutorials??

Thanks Again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the answer is absolutely not.

In order to authorize your app a user has to enter their facebook username and facebook password on facebook site and you need web browser for this. There is no way to skip this step (you can't ask what their username and password are and then exchange it automatically for access token). You can read more about this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop).

Comment: Why do you need a web browser to do this?  Why can't I build an app that behaves exactly like a web browser in regards to the POST/GET and response codes and not implement a UI?  A web browser isn't magical, it's a program like any other.  The UI is irrelevant. Embed the correct protocols, implement no UI and, as far as any website knows, it's a browser.

Comment: @KevinDTimm So then your answer is - it is possible to do it without a browser, only you need to implement your own browser :) Sure, it is possible in such case. Also if you care about legal issues it is against facebook tos to ask users for their facebook passwords.

Comment: No, not your own browser - not even close, think - wget.  And, in regards to TOS - that's the implementers problem - I only answered what it was possible to do technically.  I have no knowledge of what their TOS are (and it wasn't part of the question)

Comment: @KevinDTimm So which question were you answering then - is it possible to emulate a browser? Question was about facebook authorization, and facebook doesn't provide any API to login using username and password, nor they allow it legally. I think it is enough to call it "not possible".

Comment: I also read facebook documentation and it seems we can not do it and even for desktop application we need to use web browser and redirect user to fb page. Thank you serg and KevinDTimm for your time to answer my doubt.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question and it's answered but I thought 'horse mouth GET'. From Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/...

> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not
>   include explicit desktop app support.
>   However, if your desktop app can embed
>   a web browser (most desktop frameworks
>   such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support
>   embedding browsers), you can use the
>   client-side flow with one
>   modification: a specific redirect_uri.
>   Rather than requiring desktop apps to
>   host a web server and populate the
>   Site URL in the Developer App, we
>   provide a specific URL you can use
>   with desktop apps:
>   **https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html**...[cont]

Answer (score 1):

absolutely yes, but, we'll need to know which programming language you want to use before we can give much advice.

For example, it's possible using httpclient for java and python to encapsulate all the functionality you need, others can chime in with libraries that they use for C, C++, perl, etc.

[edit]
search for httpclient and how it's used with python.  if you run wireshark on your system, you will be able to watch the data interchange (if you don't understand the http protocol completely) and then implement that in your code.
[/edit]

Comment: I want to use Python. I tried creating one but there i am invoking browser, and now want to modify it to eliminate that. Can u point me to any Tutorial/link.

Comment: Loving those '6 years after the fact downvotes without explanation' /s

Answer (score 1):

Some good links in this regard:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/289/

https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/
http://csharpsdk.org/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now you can, if you're a beta tester for their newest feature: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/ Reminds me of PIN's on Wifi

Comment: It still requires user to enter stuff in a browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no,

I've had the same problem with my server. It was console only, so I had to make a solution. First I've logged in using the lobo java webbrowser. I've transfered the cookies of lobo to my server.