# OAuth desktop applications

Tags: .net, oauth, desktop-application, shopify

(Copy/pasting emailed question to apps@shopify.com here for the community’s benefit.)

=====

Hi,

I’m developing a private desktop application that accesses orders and fulfillment information
This is so the warehouse people can get automated reports every so often without them interacting with a  web browser.

We tried using basic auth but it seems to work only for user-agent access.
Whenever we use it from a desktop application, it doesn’t let us access any data at all.

We tried using oauth but the workflow for a desktop application is odd (being polite) and it seems also non supported (desktop app workflow).

How do I get an in-house private desktop application up and running?

We are using .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this other answer at [Is it possible to create a desktop app using facebook oauth 2.0 authentication without requiring a browser interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936813/is-it-possible-to-create-a-desktop-app-using-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-w/5049806#5049806), your application should open/embed a web browser that does the same thing as a web app requesting author and redirects to a local URL that encodes the computed password. I advise the use of a protocol handler like what itunes://whatever does makes this easy.

Alternatively, if you’re only going to do this once, you could manually compute the password with the [legacy password scheme](http://api.shopify.com/legacy_authentication.html) (all you need is the token t and you compute the rest by hand) and manually configure your desktop application with this password.